# mvn install can't find my local artifcat installed on local repository

Tags: java, maven-3

when i'm trying to build my project `mvn clean install` i'm having issues on one of my artifcat  **`com.opengroup.pop:jpop-services-tools:jar:1.3.0`**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.opengroup.pop</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpop-front-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${jpop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

here is the stack trace

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project justice-spark-scelles-rdd-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project fr.gouv.justice.spark:justice-spark-scelles-rdd-app:jar:1.0.0: The
 following artifacts could not be resolved: com.opengroup.pop:jpop-front-tools:jar:1.3.0, com.opengroup.pop:jpop-services-tools:jar:1.3.0, com.opengroup.pop:jpop-zdao-tools:jar:1.3.0
: Failure to find com.opengroup.pop:jpop-front-tools:jar:1.3.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until th
e update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

the problem is this artifcat is pressent on my local repository, i can't understand what is the problem
[image]
[image]

My local repository is well configured

```
<localRepository>D:/repository</localRepository>

mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T21:39:06+02:00)
Maven home: D:\Envirement\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: The error is complaining about jpop-front-tools, but your screenshot is of jpop-service-tools. You have jpop-front-tools in your repository, right?

Comment: yes i have all jpop dependancy on my local repository

Comment: did you try 'forcing' the update? (just in case)

Comment: yes i did mvn install -o , and get the same

Answer (score 1):

Check the content of the package itself. My guess is that it will be empty / invalid.

Delete the entire package from your local repository and rebuild. A lot of times it seems that the package is corrupted. When it downloads check it again.